# How to save an editor state in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, save, editor, pde

I have created an Editor which opens from a view.

More specifically, I have created an editor class which extends `EditorPart` and an editor input which extends `IEditorInput`. I also have created a view, where if you double click an element in the view, the editor will open. The editor simply shows a tree.

Everything works well. What I need to do is, to save the state of the editor when I change it, for example when I add a treeItem to the tree.

I've read some tutorials, but most of them explain how to save a view state by using mementos. I'm newbie in Eclipse development, so please bear with me :P

Comment: This is rather a broad question. Most editors are editing or creating a file, is this not the case here?

Comment: If the editor supports a file extension, for example .txt, the saving process is automatic since the changes are made to the file. In my case, it is kind of graphical, not text, since it shows a tree, so it cannot be saved as a file. My guess is that you somehow save the tree elements inside the memento, then the memento is saved as an xml file like a view, but I cant pull that off, atm :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a file to save in you could put the data in the 'state location' for your plugin - this is a folder in the workspace .metadata/.plugins directory which your plugin can use as you like.

You get the state location using:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("your plugin id");

IPath stateLoc = Platform.getStateLocation(bundle);
```

Note: There are several ways to get the `Bundle`, for example you can also use:

```
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());
```

which returns the bundle for the current class.

You can save / restore your file in any format you like. You mention the Memento format. Write a memento using:

```
XMLMemento memento = XMLMemento.createWriteRoot("root");

 ... add your entries

try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("file name"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) 
 {
    memento.save(writer);
 }
```

Read the memento with something like:

```
try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("file name"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) 
 {
   IMemento memento = XMLMemento.createReadRoot(reader);

   ... read the memento contents
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That path is certainly very useful for saving the data. I find your approach very good. I will do it that way.